# TSQL Comma Delimited fields on same row

Tags: t-sql

Imagine you have a User table with FirstName, MiddleName, LastName.
For the sake of this sample only FirstName is mandatory.

What's the fastest way to concatenate these 3 fields and separate them with a "," when their value is NOT null, so:

If only FirstName is NOT null, we should get "John" as result.
If only FirstName and LastName are not null, we should have "John,Wayne" as result.
If FirstName, MiddleName and LastName are not null, we should have "John,M,Wayne" as result.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
FirstName +(CASE WHEN MiddleName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ','+MiddleName END)
+(CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ','+LastName END)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 different methods

```
--syntax
select Firstname + isnull(',' +Middlename, '') + coalesce(',' +LastName, '')
from 
--testdata
(select 'John' firstname, 'W' middlename, 'Wayne' lastname
union all select 'John' firstname, null middlename, 'Wayne' lastname
union all select 'John' firstname, 'W' middlename, null lastname) a
```